# Find by linked fields Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that works like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :deals
...
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :clients
...
class Clients < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :deal
```

If I want to find all the clients listed on a certain deal I can enter `Client.find_by(deal_id: x)` in the console where x is the deal ID I want, but when I try to list them all on a page I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the relevant resource route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :deals, only: [:show]
end
```

I think the problem is I'm not doing the find correctly in the controller

```
class DealsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @deal = Deal.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @client = Client.find_by(deal_id: params[:id])
  end
end
```

On the page I'm trying to list clients like this:

```
<div class="client">
  <% @client.each do |c| %>
    <%= c.name %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But the error is `undefined method each' for #<Client:0x007f8e4cdecfb0>`

I thought it would be pretty simple because the :id that's returned from `/deal/:id` is shared by both, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find_by will return only one object, each is a method defined for arrays.
So if you want clients for a particular deal, you can do

```
@deal = Deal.find_by_id(params[:id])    
@clients = @deal.clients
```

or

```
@deal = Deal.find_by_id(params[:id])
@clients = Client.where(deal_id: params[:id])
```

and in view

```
<% @clients.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect, this works great! Will accept as soon as the wait period is over.

Comment: I have made the variable `@clients` so that it is more meaningful. Also you can use `@deal.clients` directly in the view.